# adding required property option not working

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to add property options to my model. I have a StringProperty and I added `required=True` but I'm still able to create an object with the required field being empty.

I tried it in the admin and also in my update form for the specific model so not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: required=True always works, so you are doing something wrong, I suggest you include your model definition. It won't work in the admin console.  Are you sure its empty - None and not a string with a value of "" which is not an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

You can *create* it, but can you `put` it?

```
class x(ndb.Model):
    author = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

a = x()
a.put()
```

Fails with: `BadValueError: Entity has uninitialized properties: **author**`

Setting a value on the required property author allows you to save it:

```
a.author = "some_value"
```

The put can now succeed.

```
key = a.put()
```

and `key` is now:

```
Key('x', 5707702298738688)
```

or even `key.urlsafe()`

```
ahNzfnNoYXJlZC1wbGF5Z3JvdW5kcg4LEgF4GICAgICArpkKDKIBEDYwNTM4Njc2MzY2NTQwODA
```

Read more about [storing data here.](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/#storing)

Comment: strange, as I did all that in the https://cloud-playground.appspot.com just to get the actual error msg. beats me then.